# Azure - Credit spread across multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, msdn

I have 2 subscriptions on Azure, both of which have MSDN credit associated to each subscription.

At the moment each subscription has an equal amount of credit, however all my virtual machines and cloud services reside on one of the subscriptions, meaning the credit runs down a lot quicker than the other available subscription.

Is there any way to transfer or migrate credit across subscriptions, so I can make the most of the credit available?

Comment: Instead of transferring or migrating credit across subscription, can't you redistribute Virtual Machines/Cloud Services so that each subscription consumes resources accordingly? Just curious.

Comment: We could and that would probably be the way forward, though I would like to know if it's possible either having credit unified spread over subscriptions. I doub't it because of the way subscriptions work at the moment

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think you can move credits from one subscription to another (though I may be wrong). You may want to talk to Azure support to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transfer free credit between them.  The idea of the MSDN credit is for Development and test (not production) purposes for the individuals who have the subscription, so things should be torn down regularly anyway.

There is such a thing as "Organizational Accounts" coming into azure (I think it's still in preview.  Although that doesn't unify individual allowances, it does allow control over the individual's accounts.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/dn531048.aspx

Azure MSDN benefit details http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/msdn-benefits-details/